# How can i prevent recyclerview scrolling to start when i load more data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am trying to build a news feed using cardviews listed in a recyclerview. Problem is, when I load more data by scrolling, it is automatically scrolling to top of page. I want to know how I can prevent this.

I have overrided the `onScrolled` method of `Recyclerview`'s `onScrollListener` to load more data. I am adding new data to an Arraylist every time with my `fetchingJSON()` function. Then I am calling `setupRecycler()` function to setup `Recyclerview` with my updated Arraylist.

So let's say that I loaded 4 news at beginning, then I scrolled to bottom of page and loaded 4 more news. Its just adding new data to Arraylist and kind of re-creating `recyclerview`. I think that's why there's not much difference in installing 8 news at first.But I don't know what to do to avoid that.

```
/*Here I am controlling if user has reached to bottom of page, and calling fetchingJSON() function.*/

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int visibleItemCount = lManager.getChildCount();
                int totalItemCount = lManager.getItemCount();
                int firstVisibleItemPosition = lManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();


                if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                        && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                        && totalItemCount >= PAGE_SIZE && !isLoading) {

                    newsFeed.this.postPage++;
                    fetchingJSON();

                }
            }
        });
```

Then in fetchingJSON() function, i am calling parseJSONData function to parse response.
I'm not doing this in onResponse because volley's asynchronous operation causes some problems

```
private void fetchingJSON() {
        isLoading = true;
        String url = getResources().getString(R.string.haberUrl); 
        StringRequest jsonStringRequest = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        parseJSONData(response);
                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                .
                .
                .
```

In parseJSONData function ; I am getting the data from JSON response, setting my object's attributes with that. Than adding my object to Arraylist. Finally I am calling setupRecycler function to re-create my Recyclerview with updated data .

```
public void parseJSONData(String response) {

        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");


            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                haberModel1.setTitle(dataobj.getString("header"));
                haberModel1.setUrl(dataobj.getString("picture"));
                haberModel1.setId(dataobj.getString("id"));
                haberModelArrayList.add(haberModel1);
                setupRecycler();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(""+TAG,e.printStackTrace() );
        }
    }
```

```
private void setupRecycler() {
        lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lManager);
        rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(this, haberModelArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
        isLoading = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `rvAdapter` is non-null, then add items to it and call `notifyItemRangeInserted()` instead of creating a new adapter:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

            haberModel1.setTitle(dataobj.getString("header"));
            haberModel1.setUrl(dataobj.getString("picture"));
            haberModel1.setId(dataobj.getString("id"));
            haberModelArrayList.add(haberModel1);
            // remove line: setupRecycler();
        }
        // Add these lines
        if (rvAdapter != null){
            int itemCount = rvAdapter.getItemCount();
            // TODO: add method setItems() to your adapter
            rvAdapter.setItems(haberModelArrayList);
            rvAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(itemCount, dataArray.length());
        } else {
            setupRecycler();
        }
```